# known class method for React Native OneSignal

Tags: reactjs, notifications, signals, push, native

I am trying set up One Signal for Push Notification on React Native.
But when I build in I receive `No known class method for selector 'didReceiveRemoteNotification:'` error.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>
#import "RCTOneSignal.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize oneSignal = _oneSignal;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  self.oneSignal = [[RCTOneSignal alloc] initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions
                                                         appId:@"xxxxxxxxx"];


}

// Required for the notification event.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)notification {
  [RCTOneSignal didReceiveRemoteNotification:notification];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are following an old guide of some kind. `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is not a required method anymore and is not implemented in the SDK.

I would suggest removing the `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method and your project should successfully compile.

You can always find the latest instructions on the master readme for the SDK: https://github.com/geektimecoil/react-native-onesignal#adding-the-code